# How do you program to interface in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java we can have code like this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can we do that in Kotlin?

Comment: List is an interface

Comment: Here`val a = ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: If your list is mutable `val a: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()`

Comment: The point of using `List` rather than `ArrayList` is that you don't need to propagate a change of `ArrayList` to e.g. `LinkedList` since that's just a detail. With kotlin's `val` you also don't have to change a type, so you mostly don't have to do anything here. You just use interfaces in return types & parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can see basic usage of the list and set types below:

```
val numbers: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
val readOnlyView: List<Int> = numbers
println(numbers)        // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
numbers.add(4)
println(readOnlyView)   // prints "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
readOnlyView.clear()    // -> does not compile

val strings = hashSetOf("a", "b", "c", "c")
assert(strings.size == 3)
```

For more information check this page:
[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html)

Comment: There's also `listOf` for immutable lists

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin programming to the interface is often times not needed, since it has type inference. You can simply write:

```
val someList = ArrayList<String>()
someList.add("Hello")
```

and if you ever change the type of the list you don't have to change the delclaration:

```
val someList = MyCustomListWichCanOnlyHoldStrings()
someList.add("Hello")
```

If you really want you can still specify the interface manually like this:

```
val someList: List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
someList.add("Hello")
```

---

**Edit:**

I just want to elaborate a little more, why you program to the interface in Java.

When you write all your code like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> giveMeSomeList() {
    ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add("some");
    return someList;
}
```

And you want to change the list type to `LinkedList` you need to change the code in at least three places above.

When you program against the interface like this:

```
public List<String> giveMeSomeList() {
    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add("some");
    return someList;
}
```

you only need to chage the code in the initialization and the rest of the code can be left as is.

---

In Kotlin we don't have this problem since the type gets inferred. When you don't write the type you don't have to change it if the type changes.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted this question two different ways, so I'm gonna write this answer containing both:

1. Using Lists in Kotlin

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf(/*items*/)//Similar to ArrayList
var immutableList = listOf(/*items*/)//You can't add or remove
```

They can be initialized without any items, but it requires the diamond operator to specify the type.

You should use the Kotlin initialization methods when creating lists though. ArrayList has `arrayListOf<Type>(items)`
The code you had in the question would be:

```
val list: List<String> = mutableListOf()
```

or

```
val List: List<String> = listOf()
```

There's also `arrayListOf` (as I mentioned earlier) and, not directly a list, but `setOf`.

2. Declaring a superclass type (i.e. List) but initializing a child-class

When you do:

```
val /*var*/ someField = SomeClass()
```

in Kotlin, someField gets automatic type inference, which here is SomeClass. When you do `mutableListOf<SomeClass>`, the inferred type is `MutableList<SomeClass>`. So, if you want to specify a specific child, you need to manually write the type:

```
val /*var*/ someList: List<SomeClass> = mutableListOf()
```

Just like in Java, just with different syntax.